# Copy ListBox Items to TextBoxes

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am attempting to use a CommandButton to populate TextBoxes in a Userform based on the entries in a ListBox and can't find a way to make it work.

The below code works to populate the first TextBox (TextBox2), but everything below is coming in blank. You'll notice I added & "" after TextBox3-11 - that's because I was receiving an "Invalid Use of Null" error.

How do I get each item in the ListBox to populate in it's corresponding TextBox?

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Dim i As Long
i = ListBox1.ListIndex
With Me.ListBox1
TextBox2.Text = .List(i, 0)
TextBox3.Text = .List(i, 1) & ""
TextBox4.Text = .List(i, 2) & ""
TextBox5.Text = .List(i, 3) & ""
TextBox6.Text = .List(i, 4) & ""
TextBox7.Text = .List(i, 5) & ""
TextBox8.Text = .List(i, 6) & ""
TextBox9.Text = .List(i, 7) & ""
TextBox10.Text = .List(i, 8) & ""
TextBox11.Text = .List(i, 9) & ""
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the `ColumnCount` property of `ListBox1` set to?

Comment: ColumnCount is 1 and to clarify, everything in the ListBox is in a single column. I'm trying to get rows 9-10 to move to their corresponding TextBoxes

Comment: Why would you do it that way? So you are using what as a delimiter? You need to split that into its values. Seems like an odd way to do it.

Comment: The TextBoxes will be used to populate information elsewhere on a spreadsheet.

Regarding a delimiter, I'm lost. Can you recommend how I would go about doing that?

Comment: I would need to see how you are populating your listbox. I still say you should use columns in your listbox tho - if you did, then the code you posted above would work.

Comment: You've said ColumnCount is 1 (i.e. there's only ***one column*** - '0' ), yet you're trying to load `TextBox3.Text = .List(i, 1)` which is loading the ***second column*** into textbox3..?

Comment: In`ListBox1` you probably loaded it as a single dimension array.  You are accessing it like a multi-dimensional array.  Change `.List(i, 0)` to `.List(0)`, and so on through `List(i, 9)` to `.List(9)`.